# Using ng-if with multiple conditions in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm trying to add a button that only shows for particular index numbers:

```
            <tbody data-ng-repeat="(wholesalerIndex,wholesaler) in wholesalers">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button ng-if="$index != 0 || $index != 3" class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="removeWholesaler(wholesaler, wholesalerIndex)">Up</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="removeWholesaler(wholesaler, wholesalerIndex)">Down</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

ng-if isn't working. It works fine when I have 1 condition `ng-if="$index != 0"`, but when I try to add the OR (||) statement it stops working.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Just a thought - perhaps the order of operations is getting screwed up. Try using parenthesis like this: ($index != 0) || ($index != 3)

Comment: Actually - it looks like the logic is off. If Index equals 3, it is not equal to 0 so it passes. If the index equals 0, it's not equal to 3 so it passes. If index = 10000 it is neither equal to 0 (so it passes) nor equal to 3 (so it also passes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is the logic is off. Try logical and instead of logical or.

```
<button ng-if="$index != 0 && $index != 3" class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="removeWholesaler(wholesaler, wholesalerIndex)">Up</button>
```

Comment: This solves it. But why would that qualify as true when index is only zero at the moment?

Comment: As angular iterates through each wholesaler the $index is set. ng-if tests that $index as it passes through the loop. If the index is 0, the "$index != 3" test will pass because 0 is not 3. Vice-versa when $index is 3, it will pass the "$index != 0" test. By using logical AND, the overall test indicates that $index may not be zero AND $index may not be three. Otherwise, the test is truthy.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ng-show it will work :)

```
<tbody data-ng-repeat="(wholesalerIndex,wholesaler) in wholesalers">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button ng-show="$index != 0 || $index != 3" class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="removeWholesaler(wholesaler, wholesalerIndex)">Up</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="removeWholesaler(wholesaler, wholesalerIndex)">Down</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I hope that this helps.

Comment: wholesaler index is an internal primary key which is different.

Comment: Right! Try using the `ng-show` directive instead of `ng-if`